# Get value of a check box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am a newbie to jquery.
I have this code written. I want to get the value of 'newValue' when the checkbox is checked. But this code returns 'undefined'.

Please can someone help to get the state of the checkbox: the return value should be true or false, 1 or 0.

```
$(tableCell).empty();
/Checkbox
 $('<input type="checkbox" checked class="EditContactRow" style="width: 20%" />').appendTo($(tableCell)).val(controlValue).blur(function () {
  var newValue = $(tableCell).find('checkbox').val();
.....
.....
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should read the help pages on how to format code in your question

Comment: Everything is wrong here...

Comment: Be sure to format your comment correctly : `//Checkbox` or `//Comment` also remove the `....`. Just copy the code as it is in your editor.

Comment: No its not duplicate of that @rnevius, the issue here is syntax..

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy, Olumide Omolayo

your code seems a little bit messy but it can be fixed for sure. Where is your HTML, would you please add it to your question?

If you need an example: if you have a checkbox you would take it's value by selecting it like this

```
var myCheckboxValue = $('#myCheckbox').val();
```

your code:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" checked class="EditContactRow" style="width: 20%" />')
```

will not work. since $() is used to access jQuery selectors, those SELECT an element in the HTML/DOM, then you do something with the element. (see this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gy7KuBwJ6nc))

If you want to ADD an element to the HTML/DOM you'd probably use something like

`$("#myDiv").html('my html that will be added to the element with id="myDiv"');`

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask more :)

P.S. If you post your full code here, we might able to help you much more than just write at random here. People might be able to actually give you the fixed version :)

Answer (score 0):

just a small syntax error.

Change this line `var newValue = $(tableCell).find('checkbox').val();`

to

`var newValue = $(tableCell).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();`

The problem was `.find('checkbox')` you are trying to find a element who's name is `checkbox` and you dont have one.. the attempt should be to **find a element 's whos type is "checkbox"** so use the syntax `.find('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: The solution given by Reddy solved the problem for me. Thank you all.

Comment: @OlumideOmolayo Glad I could help you. Also can you accept this answer if this fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to my question from Reddy

var newValue = $(tableCell).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();

Thank you all